# Google Script: Getting style attributes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Trying to get the style attributes for an image.

So what i do is:

```
var attr = img.getAttributes()
for (var att in attr) {
   Logger.log(att + ":" + attr[att]);
 }
```

However, theh output has something weird, i get [object object]?

```
[14-12-10 17:35:46:432 CET] LINK_URL:null
[14-12-10 17:35:46:433 CET] HEIGHT:100
[14-12-10 17:35:46:434 CET] WIDTH:100
[14-12-10 17:35:46:463 CET] [object Object]
```

How do i get behind that object?

Comment: Could you add more code? for example the way you're getting that image.

Answer (score 0):

first, be careful when using the .getAttributes() method. It has a bug that Google has acknowledged that it will return null for most attributes that have the same value as the Paragraph Style. Please star the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4286&q=attributes&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner).

The problem with your results is that .getAttributes() returns a object and some of the object's properties names are Enums. In that case you are probably retrieving the Horizontal Alignment. The problem is that your Logger call is trying to stringfy the Enum and this is not possible, returning [object Object].

Try the following:

```
Logger.log(att);
Logger.log(attr[att]);
```

To see the property name and its value